# What is the order of execution of the goroutine when working with channels?

Tags: go

What is the order of execution of goroutines when working with channels? I thought that writing or reading to a channel stops the current goroutine. But I have test code that doesn't follow this rule:

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go sum(ch, 3)
    fmt.Println("Write number: 10")
    ch <- 10
    fmt.Println("Write number: 20")
    ch <- 20
    fmt.Println("Write number: 30")
    ch <- 30

    fmt.Println("Finish main")
}

func sum(ch chan int, len int) {
    fmt.Println("Func 'sum' start")

    sum := 0
    for i := 0; i < len; i++ {
       fmt.Println("For start")
       num := <-ch
       fmt.Printf("Read from ch: %d\n", num)
       sum += num
       fmt.Println("For finish")
    }

    fmt.Printf("Sum: %d\n", sum)
}
```

How I think this program working:

1. Create a channel

2. Create a goroutine (do not launch, only initialize)

3. Print: Write down the number: 10

4. Record to channel 10. Lock the main function.

5. The main thing is blocked. Start the sum goroutine.

6. Print the sum function: Func 'sum' start

7. The summation function runs in a loop and prints: "To begin"

8. Read the number 10 from “ch” and print: “Read from ch: 10”

9. Next step. Print: "To complete" and move on to the next iteration.

10. Print: “To begin with” and try to write “with”. But the channel is empty. Stop the amount and go to the main

....And again and again.

Then I want to see:

```
Write number: 10
Func 'sum' start
For start
Read from ch: 10
For finish
For start
Write number: 20
Read from ch: 20
For finish
For start
Write number: 30
Read from ch: 30
For finish
Sum: 60
Finish main
```

But, i see that:

```
Write number: 10
Func 'sum' start
For start
Read from ch: 10
For finish
For start
Write number: 20
Write number: 30
Read from ch: 20
For finish
For start
Read from ch: 30
For finish
Sum: 60
Finish main
```

How that is possible? Main function write in channel twice without reading.
Also, if you change the number of calls in a for:

```
go sum(ch, 2)
```

I won't get an error. But there was no one to read the last message

Example: Before this message.

Comment: Because the main program and the go-routine run at the same time.The print is random. If you add `time.Sleep` before print `Write number`, then the order will be clear [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/bnGRK2UAl6Z).

Comment: Consider reading [this](https://go.dev/ref/mem) to gain full understanding of the guarantees provided by goroutines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Goroutines run concurrently. On systems with multiple cores they may run in parallel. Details are up the scheduler implementation in the Go runtime. For all intents and purposes, things happen in random order, except synchronizing operations such as channel communication.

> How is it possible that the main function writes to the channel twice without reading.

It is not and that is not what is happening (as long as the channel is unbuffered). The Println call happens before the send operation and the main goroutine blocks after printing until the sum goroutine is ready to receive.

It is also random if you will see "Read from ch: 30" printed or not. The corresponding receive operation must happen, because main is blocked until it does. However, main may return before the Println after the receive happens, and the program terminates immediately when main returns, no matter if any other goroutines exist. The likelihood of that happening increases if the channel is buffered.

> Also, if you change the number of calls in a for I won't get an error.

That is not true. If there are only two receives that always results in a deadlock: https://go.dev/play/p/qFVh529mkqR